# Determining why HTMLButtonElement.type is submit

Tags: html, angular, forms, dom, button

I need to automatically change the type of buttons in my Frankensteinian Angular / .NET WebForms application, to be `type="button"` when a directive is applied to the button. However, I don't want to change *all* buttons; Just the buttons that haven't been explicitly set to `type="submit"`.

In short:

```html
<button my-directive type="submit">An intentional Submit button</button>

<button my-directive>A button I would like to have changed to type="button" by my-directive</button>
```

Code for Angular directive:

```
@Directive({selector: 'button[my-directive]'})
class MyDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  el = inject(ElementRef) as ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.type) {
      this.el.nativeElement.type = 'button';
    }
  }
}
```

When I step through in the debugger, "type" is submit on both buttons even when it hasn't been explicitly set. How can I detect the difference?

Comment: Use `getAttribute`. The `<button>` tag's default `type` is `submit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the correct code is:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.el.nativeElement.hasAttribute('type') || this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('type') !== 'submit') {
      this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    }
}
```